# How to disable reload when a tab is created dynamically?

Tags: jquery, tabs

I use jQuery dynamically create tabs, but each time I click one tab, it will reload the target URL again. How should I disable the reload behavior unless I want it reloads again?
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `event.preventDefault()`:

```
$('a.tab').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // this is the key
    // your code here
});
```

**Edit**: Regarding your comment – just [set `cache` to true](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#options):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $apTabs = $("#apTabs").tabs({
        // ...
        cache: true, // this does the magic
        // ...
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer :-), but disable default event will cause my selected tab not show. I need show content retrieved from initial load, just want preventing it from asking content from server again. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#tabs').click(function(){
  // code
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Post my code for your reference:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $apTabs = $("#apTabs").tabs({
            ajaxOptions: { async: true },
            cache: false,
            add: function (event, ui) {
                //immdeiately select the new created one
                $apTabs.tabs('select', '#' + ui.panel.id);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="apTabs">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <div></div>
</div>
```